# Make MSBuild use new Roslyn compiler in VS15 Preview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I just recently delved into Roslyn compiler stuff and I'm wondering about some possibilities. I'm trying to build Roslyn compiler from Roslyn repository  using `features/tuples` branch and replace the needed DLLs in `VS15Preview\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` folder. But when I replace DLLs and build console app project I receive the following error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error     The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Files which I try to replace: `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll`, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.dll` and `csc.exe`.

Is it possible to build your custom Roslyn compiler for C# and replace it within VS15 Preview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of going about it is to set the [CscToolPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) msbuild variable to your new roslyn build's bin directory.

I find the msbuild commandline (e.g. Start > Developer Command Prompt) the most convenient for this. You can just `cd` into any solution directory on run:

```
msbuild /p:CscToolPath=<PathToYourRoslynBinDir>`
```

You can also do it inside a `.csproj` if you do it more often:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CscToolPath>C:\your\roslyn\bin</CscToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Obviously, this only affects the build, not Visual Studio or it's intellisense. To hook that up, you need to follow the [Trying Your Changes in Visual Studio](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5980aca16e60b324c158957306c2f4d61252fdb6/docs/contributing/Building%2C%20Debugging%2C%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md#trying-your-changes-in-visual-studio) guide in the Roslyn repo. You have to build one of the VSIX projects in the Roslyn solution. Running one of those projects launches an experimental instance of Visual Studio where you can play around with your changes.

Comment: It seems to work and it seems that it's what I was looking for. But I have a little question. I changed some tuple stuff and my VS15 says that there are some errors, but when I compile the project using 'msbuild' approach I have no problems whatsoever.

Can I also tell VS15 to hookup my changed dlls in order to not show me these error messages in the editor itself? Because obviously VS15 uses other dlls. It seems that all required dlls are placed here %MSBuildToolsPath%. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

M0sa's answer might work, however, that will only give you MSBuild enabled builds. If you also want to test it in VS, then you can follow [Roslyn's own documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/contributing/Building,%20Debugging,%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md). That page tell you how to replace the "intellisense" in Visual Studio (the **VisualStudioSetup** bullet), and the Ctrl-Shift-B "Build Solution" to actually run your solution (the **CompilerExtension**).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to try out your build of Roslyn, you can do that by opening Roslyn.sln in VS15 and then running the Roslyn project (with or without debugging). It will start a new instance of VS15, which uses your build of Roslyn.

Comment: No, I want to use my Roslyn build with the existing VS15 Preview editor, not  the experimental one.