# How is Roslyn related to MsBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

I'm wondering: How exactly is Roslyn related to MsBuild?

My understanding was that

1. Roslyn is a compilation engine
2. MsBuild is is mostly a set of specifications of how a project is set
   up - i.e. basically a definition schema for .csproj, .sln files and
   so on.

Then again, MsBuild also ships with an msbuild.exe - which, correct me if I'm wrong, is able to actually compile projects. But how would this tie in with Roslyn, assuming msbuild.exe can compile projects, but so can Roslyn?

Does msbuild.exe use Roslyn to compile, in case of MSBuild 15? Are they completely seperate? Am I misunderstanding anything?

And furthermore & more specifally: Assuming I want programatically create simple .csproj files, and use Roslyn's MSBuildWorkspace to handle/populate and finally compile these.
Would the end user of my application need to have Microsoft's build tools installed on their machine? Or is this not necessary, as Roslyn would be able to read & compile these independently of any local MSBuild installation?

Comment: If you are building an extensions you can pack all of the dlls you need into it

Comment: "MSBuild" => `msbuild.exe`, "Roslyn" => `csc.exe`.

Comment: @johnny5 any idea which ones those would be? Any NuGet package? Tried ages getting MSBuildWorkspace to work on a machine that doesn't have msbuild 15 installed. Faced very weird errors; some changes to the workspace worked and were saved to the csproj files etc correctly, others crashed with pretty meaningless NullReferenceExecptions and such. Same code worked on a machine where MSBuild 15 was installed though

Comment: @Bogey,  Err... Roslyn is very buggy I've had several issues with Roslyn when trying to implement.   Alot of the time I was working Roslyn would find ambiguities in the DDLs and not no how to handle properly and just Throw a random generic error.  You might have to delete your MEF Component Cache from your hive

Comment: Somewhat related - [Make MSBuild use new Roslyn compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221813/make-msbuild-use-new-roslyn-compiler-in-vs15-preview).

Comment: I recently saw a youtube video which is demo-ing AOP with Roslyn https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D52Y8mYKvDk (I don't work for that company and don't know how helpful the video is in practice)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

MSbuild is the build system for Visual Studio.  It calls the C# compiler to compile C# projects.  Roslyn is the C# compiler (and the VB compiler).  So msbuild uses Roslyn.

However, Roslyn also includes more things than just the compiler.  It also includes a VS plug in that gives you IDE features (completion lists, colorization, code fixes, etc).

In addition, Roslyn is also an API for analyzing source code, that you can use from your own app.  For this last scenario is has an API known as MSBuildWorkspace that you can use to open a project or solution for analysis. This workspace uses MSBuild to figure out all the pieces of the projects and solution.  So this part of Roslyn uses MSBuild.

Comment: "MSbuild is the build system for Visual Studio." Just to be pedantic, you can also use MSBuild without Visual Studio by launching msbuild.exe. This is commonly done in build systems.

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks. Now that there are popular alternatives to Visual Studio (like Rider), the comment of RenniePet is meaningful. Onemay use Rider as EDI, that uses msbuild as compiler. One also may use Rider as EDI that uses Roslyn for its static analyzers.